# How would I code the following using enumitem?

Tags: lists, enumitem

I would really (really) appreciate it if someone could give me the code in enumitem that does the following:

I need just one indexing set (roman numerals) and the flexibility to change space between items in the list; space between the left vertical margin and the items in the list; and the space before and after the list of items.

I have been trying for a day to get this and have been left a broken man.

Comment: Have you looked at the basic [`list`](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-260.html)?

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE builds a new list type and fiddles with the parameters you request. (In fact, you don't need to build a new list type, but can drop the `\newlist` command and replace `newenum` with enumerate henceforth.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{newenum}{enumerate}{1} %1 is max depth
\setlist[newenum,1]%set params for list level 1
{ label=(\arabic*), %arabic labelling
  itemindent=0.9cm, % hor. space before "bullet"
  labelsep=0.4cm, % hor. space between "bullet" and label
  itemsep=0.5cm, % ver. space between items
  topsep=1cm % ver. space before and after list
} 

\begin{document}
List Starts.

\begin{newenum}
 \item List 
 \item Continues
\end{newenum}

List Over.
\end{document}
```

Using that, you can fiddle with the spacing parameters quite easily. The horizontal spacing is very customisable, so I recommend checking out Sections 3.2 and 3.3 of the [`enumitem` manual](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf) to achieve precisely what you want.

Comment: This does not compile with the `standalone` class. Change it to `article`.

Comment: @azetina, huh, really? :) It works perfectly fine with `standalone` for me. (I'll change it anyways, though not sure why it would make a difference.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This was the kind of thing I was looking for. I really like the flexibility it gives me. However, there doesn't seem to be a way of getting the vertical space between the start of the list and the thing above (e.g. a lemma) to anything less than what look likes roughly a `\bigskip`. Aesthetically this is a problem for me as I'm a using vertical spacing of `\medskip` for most of my document.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being an idiot. It's all working beautifully. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I have one slight glitch with your answer: how do I make the bullet points align with the left margin? Cheers.

Comment: You asked for "space between the left vertical margin and the items in the list" ... that's a feature of the answer, not a bug! :P ... Anyways, I digress. Swap `itemindent=0.9cm, labelsep=0.4cm` for `leftmargin=*`.